# How to open an activity on notification click

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send custom notifications to the users, now i want that when an user clicks on the notification an activity should open.

Here is my code snippet from mainActivity.java:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("MyNotification", "MyNotification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
```

And below is my Service class:

```
public class MyMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    public void showNotification(String title, String message) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyNotification")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText(message);

        NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        manager.notify(999, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For click notification and go a specific activity, you should use Pending Intent. like below:

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SpecificActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then make your Notification Builder like this

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyNotification")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentText(message);
```

So your finally `showNotification()` method looks like this:

```
public void showNotification(String title, String message, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {

    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SpecificActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyNotification")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentText(message);

    NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    manager.notify(999, builder.build());
}
```

If anything you don't understand or have a query Comment here.

Comment: I mean where should i create the pending intent, showNotification() or onMessageReceived()?

Comment: You should create it on `showNotification()` Method

Comment: please look at my code which i have posted. in showNotification i have to pass paramenter and then in onMessageReceived i have called the showNotification() method.

Comment: For `pending Intent`, you don't need to pass any parameter. But for others like you need `String title, String message` you should pass this.

Comment: but it is showing error as i have not passed the parameter

Comment: Thank you for helping so patiently. This helped me

Answer (score 1):

```
           // Create an Intent for the activity you want to start
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
            // Create the TaskStackBuilder and add the intent, which inflates the back stack
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
            // Get the PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
            builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = 
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

for more information visit https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation

**EDIT**
here is the code you want

```
public class MyMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), pendingIntent);
    }

    public void showNotification(String title, String message, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyNotification")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentText(message);

        NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        manager.notify(999, builder.build());
    }
}
```